# Generate a random 9 digit number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to generate a random 9 digit number

for example `0987654321` note that each digit appear once..

i tried this :

```
select convert(numeric(10,0),rand() * 8999999999) + 10000000
```

it generates but at some point numbers repeat. but it is client need to make sure in 9 digit sequence no number appears twice..

required output like this..

```
1234567890
9870654321
1234098567
8976543120
```

Comment: You are not looking for a random number then as it is perfectly valid for a random number generator to repeat the same value.

Comment: @PaulHunt : thnaks for reply..but i worked but its client requirement its actually a some kind of ticket number generator scheme and the above condition is very much needed..

Comment: Why can't you just use an identity seeded from 100000000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are trying to generate a 10 digit number. I made it as a varchar because I don't want to supress the first 0 when applies:

```
declare @rnd varchar(10) = ''
;with a as
(
select 0 x
union all
select x + 1
from a where x < 9
), b as
(
select top 10 x from a
order by newid()
)
select @rnd += cast(x as char(1)) from b

select @rnd
```

You can also write it is a while loop:

```
DECLARE @rnd varchar(10) = '0123456789'
DECLARE @i int = len(@rnd)

;while @i > 1
  select @rnd = stuff(@rnd, rnd, 1, '') + substring(@rnd, rnd, 1), @i += -1  
  from (SELECT cast(rand(BINARY_CHECKSUM(newid()))*@i as int)+1 rnd) x

select @rnd
```

Comment: thanks will accept..this !! but is there any possibility that a number like `1234567890` may repeat ?? and can you tell me how to redirect this o/p to a text file or table... becoz i want to capture random numbers that are generated.. thank u for ur help sir !

Comment: theres always a possibility of a repeat by running the function multiple times - not a high possibility, but still there. After all there are only 10! (3,628,800) possible combinations. To avoid this you'd have to check every time that you hadn't already generated a duplicate, which for small sets of results would be fine, but for large sets I'd just insert all the combinations into a lookup table in random order (with columns ID as an Int from 0 - 3,628,800 & value), and reference the ID. then you can just get the one with the next id each time

Comment: incidently - to get all the possible combinations you'd need to implement the algorithm given at [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations) in SQL code

Answer (score 0):

As you want to insert these values in to a table, and also check for duplicated. I would do the following:

**1. Create a view to generate a NewId**

```
create view vw_getNewID as select newid() AS [NewId]
```

**2. Generate a TVF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GenerateRandomNumber()
RETURNS @r TABLE
(
RandomNumber varchar(10)
)

AS BEGIN

    ;WITH numbers as 
    (
    SELECT 0  AS [number]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT number + 1
    FROM numbers
    WHERE number  < 9
    )
    INSERT INTO @r
   SELECT stuff(
             (SELECT ''+ number FROM numbers CROSS APPLY dbo.vw_getNewID vgni order by vgni.NewId FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE

             ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')
                , 1, 1, '')

    RETURN

END
```

**3. Query your new TVF to insert into your table.**

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (RandomNumber)
SELECT grn.RandomNumber
FROM dbo.fn_GenerateRandomNumber() grn
LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable t ON t.RandomNumber = grn.RandomNumber
WHERE t.RandomNumber IS NULL
```

** Note that I have converted the output to `varchar` to preserve the leading zero.

Comment: some times the random number generated consists of only 8 digits,

Comment: thanks Barry !!but is there any possibility that a number like 1234567890 may repeat ?? and can you tell me how to redirect this o/p to a text file or table... becoz i want to capture random numbers that are generated.. thank u for ur help sir !

Comment: your solution generates 8 digits at times

Comment: @M.Ali This is because I was returning a numeric and the leading zero is removed. See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select top 10 *
from
(
select 100000000 + CONVERT(BIGINT, (9999999999-100000000+1)*RAND()) as rnd 
union
select 100000000 + CONVERT(BIGINT, (9999999999-100000000+1)*RAND()) as rnd 
union
select 100000000 + CONVERT(BIGINT, (9999999999-100000000+1)*RAND()) as rnd 
union
select 100000000 + CONVERT(BIGINT, (9999999999-100000000+1)*RAND()) as rnd
union
select 100000000 + CONVERT(BIGINT, (9999999999-100000000+1)*RAND()) as rnd
union
select 100000000 + CONVERT(BIGINT, (9999999999-100000000+1)*RAND()) as rnd
union
select 100000000 + CONVERT(BIGINT, (9999999999-100000000+1)*RAND()) as rnd
) as t
```

Comment: This produces duplicate digits in the number.

Comment: i didnt downvote but at some point it gives me this `768121209` i dont wnat that to repeat...but thanks for ur help !

Comment: @Barry I have u updated the answer this will not return duplicates, and its not truely `Random` if you are enforcing Uniqueness among returned values.

Comment: but is there any possibility that a number like 1234567890 may repeat ?? and can you tell me how to redirect this o/p to a text file or table... becoz i want to capture random numbers that are generated.. thank u for ur help sir @M.Ali :)

Comment: @george Yes I have updated my answer now it will not have any repeated numbers.

Comment: @george to get it to Text file you will need to use sql server Import/Export wizard. and to insert these values into a table simple do a `SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM... Rest of the query..`

Comment: @M.Ali This still contains duplicate digits. The random number should only contain one occurrence of any digit. This is valid `1234567890` This is not valid `874892301` (The number 8 is duplicated)